# How to combine ls -v and convert commands in linux

Tags: linux, ls

I want to convert files in a specific order. For conversion I am using this command:

```
convert *.jpg output.pdf
```

The order of the image files in the output pdf should be:

```
ls -v
```

How can I combine these 2 commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you mean this:

```
convert $(ls -v *.jpg) output.pdf
```

Using `$()` you can place the output of one command as part of an outer command.

Answer (score 0):

```
PICS=`ls -v *.jpg`
convert $PICS output.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but Alfe's answer seems a bit easier as it is only 1 step. I'll keep these commands in mind though. Maybe I will have to use them seperately ;)